# How to send XML file to ActiveMQ?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jaxb, activemq-classic, message-queue

In my application I use JAXB to convert an object to XML. I need to transfer this XML file to an ActiveMQ queue. Previously I sent the message to the queue in the form of a string like this:

```
public class Main {
    private static String url = ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL;
    private static String subject = "TestQueue";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException {
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url);
        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        connection.start();

        Session session = connection.createSession(false,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Destination destination = session.createQueue(subject);
        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination); 
        TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("secondMessage ");
        producer.send(message);
        connection.close();
    }
}
```

But now I need to transfer the XML file. How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried, why didn't what you tried work?  Details please.

Comment: I have a problem because i don't know how to send XML file to activemq queque. I did not find necessary information for my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JMS (and messaging in general) you send *messages* not files. You can turn your file into a message by reading the data from the file and putting into a JMS text or bytes message. The simplest solution would be something like this:

```
public class Main {
    private static String url = ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL;
    private static String subject = "TestQueue";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException {
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url);
        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        connection.start();

        Session session = connection.createSession(false,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Destination destination = session.createQueue(subject);
        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination); 
        String xml = readXmlFromFile();
        TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(xml);
        producer.send(message);
        connection.close();
    }

    private static String readXmlFromFile() {
        // read XML from file
    }
}
```